# How To Convert HTML Tags Into WordDoc Text Format? Using DOCX.js Library

Tags: javascript, html, docx

I am facing an issue in converting HTML text into word doc supporting format so I can generate a doc file using docx.js lib. Right now HTML tags are showing up as a plan text.

and this is the lib I am using: https://docx.js.org/

```
<p>
  <strong>voice:</strong> 
  During an address to Congress, George Washington said “If you can’t send money, send cigars.” [pause]  Or something like that.  [pause]  There’s no question that Washington was a wise man.  He knew that premium quality cigars are worth their weight in gold. And if he were alive today, he’d be running the country from the lounge at 
  <strong>No Name Cigar Company.</strong> 
  Where the conversation never comes to an end &#8211; and neither does their premier cigar selection. Mingle with legends &#8211; at 
  <strong>No Name Cigar Company.</strong>
</p> 
<p>&nbsp;</p> 
<p>Visit them online at <strong>NoNameWebsite.com</strong></p>`
```

Comment: read the documentation

Comment: From a quick read of the docs, that's not how that library works. There doesn't appear to be a way of converting HTML this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please Use [googoose](https://github.com/aadel112/googoose)
this works very fast and without glitch

here is the complete code example

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>              
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aadel112/googoose@master/jquery.googoose.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var o = {
        filename: 'test.doc'
    };
    $(document).googoose(o);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
The content that is rendered to a Word doc will need to be wrapped in a div with the classname googoose-wrapper, by default.
<div class="googoose-wrapper">  
<p><strong>voice:</strong> During an address to Congress, George Washington said “If you can’t send money, send cigars.” [pause]  Or something like that.  [pause]  There’s no question that Washington was a wise man.  He knew that premium quality cigars are worth their weight in gold. And if he were alive today, he’d be running the country from the lounge at <strong>No Name Cigar Company.</strong> Where the conversation never comes to an end &#8211; and neither does their premier cigar selection. Mingle with legends &#8211; at <strong>No Name Cigar Company.</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Visit them online at <strong>NoNameWebsite.com</strong></p> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Asif - thanks for the suggestion. I am using googoose lib to generate a word Docx file. but I am facing one issue with it. When I add images in word doc. it doesn't show up instead it show's a crossed image icon in MS Word. (this is only happening in read-only mode.).

But when editing the doc the image shows up. Can you let me know what is the correct way to use images in a word doc in this googoose lib.
Thanks!

Comment: try this, convert the image to base64 and add in your HTML then convert it into a word file let me know if the idea did not work.

Comment: Hi, Asif thanks for the suggestion but I actually replaced the library with a more reliable one. "PHPWord"